# Empty POST data in first query

Tags: php, apache, post

I have a strange problem with PHP script and sending data by POST.

Script source where I receive POST data:

```
<?php
print_r($GLOBALS);
?>
```

Script where I send POST data:

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://server.com/script.php';
    $data = array(
        "request" => '
        {
            "variable": "some data"
        }'
    );

    $options = array(
        'http' => array(
            'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method'  => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($data),
        ),
    );
    $context  = stream_context_create($options);
    echo $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
?>
```

When I call this script first time it return:

```
Array ( [GLOBALS] => Array *RECURSION* [_POST] => Array ( ) [_GET] => Array ( ) [_COOKIE] => Array ( ) [_FILES] => Array ( ) )
```

When I repeat query it's OK - Array show POST data. After a few minutes it is again empty.

I tried set different settings in .htaccess file, but it does not help.

PS. Same script on other server works great.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you're actually posting any data?

Comment: Yes, i sure. I tried send data from other PHP script, so i only refresh page and then POST data shows. PS. I tested the same script on other server and there everything was OK.

Comment: Could you show us how you're posting the data?

Comment: Yes, code below:

`$url = 'http://servername.com/script.php';
$data = array(
 "request" => '
 {
  "variable": "some data"
 }'
);

$options = array(
 'http' => array(
  'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
  'method'  => 'POST',
  'content' => http_build_query($data),
 ),
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
echo $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);`

Comment: Thanks, although you should include it in the actual question rather than a comment. It'll be easier to read.

Comment: Sorry. Question was edited.